# How to tell Gigolo / GVFS to use SMBv2 for Windows shares?

Tags: mount, samba, gvfs, gigolo

On our Windows file servers SMBv1 was switched of recently due to security problems and a password policy introduced.

Since then we can't mount any more the shares from Ubuntu 16.04 using Gigolo. We get the German Error "Einhängen der Windows-Freigabe ist fehlgeschlagen: Die Wartezeit für die Verbindung ist abgelaufen" (timeout)

Now we were able to track down the problem to SMBv1 when mounting manually:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=me //foo.local/digital /mnt
```

does not work, while

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0,username=me //foo.local/digital /mnt
```

does work.

So far so good - but we do not want to miss the comfort of mounting via Gigolo / Thunar.

How can Gigolo / Thunar (I think the both are based on GVFS) be told to use smbV2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but it comes at a price. Unlike mount.cifs gvfs and thunar use libsmbclient to access shares and it limits itself to the NT1 (SMB1) dialect.

But you can change that by editing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and adding the following to the [global] section:

```
client max protocol = SMB3
```

There's another one at the minimum but it normally isn't required to do anything with that:

```
client min protocol = SMB2
```

The server and the client will auto-negotiate the best dialect to use between those two values.

The problem is this will disable host browsing so if you go to Network in your file browser it will be empty. Accessing it by name still works but must be done explicitly.

Comment: Thanks will try. Wondering what is the reason that it disables host browsing?

Comment: Sounds like an explanation for my problem. Do you have a source why Thunar/gvfs/libsmbclient is not able to browse shares without SMB1? "host browsing" refers to listing hosts in the network or shares on one host? See also related question: https://serverfault.com/q/970998/96200

Comment: It's more than Thunar. Explorer on Win10 cannot list NetBIOS host names either for the same reason - Win10 disables SMB1 on the client side in new builds. Ubuntu came up with a workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1778322?comments=all but it has one tiny little problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107