# samba: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The network responded incorrectly

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I am trying to share a folder using the GUI (nemo) or the command line like

```
net usershare add temp /home/administrator/tmp comment Everyone:R guest_ok=y
```

In both cases I get the error message

```
net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The network responded incorrectly.
```

I found a lot of threads with similar issues, but slightly different messages, like

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The connection was refused.
```

or

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. Invalid parameter.
```

and tried the solutions mentioned there but nothing seems to solve it.

My relevant section in the smb.conf is

```
usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
usershare owner only = no
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
encrypt passwords = yes
guest ok = yes
guest account = nobody
```

I have a user nobody

```
cat /etc/passwd
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

and it has a samba password

```
sudo smbpasswd -a nobody
```

Similar commands

```
net usershare add temp /home/administrator/tmp bla nobody:F guest_ok=y
net usershare add temp /home/administrator/tmp bla nobody:F guest_ok=n
```

show the same error message.

I have some entries in `/var/lib/samba/usershares`, but can't remember how they got there, but the shares are not available.

One examples is

```
#VERSION 2
path=/home/administrator/Downloads/
comment=Everyone:R
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:R
guest_ok=n
sharename=Downloads
```

Any idea what am I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alternative in case you are interested. If you originally set the server min to SMB2 because of the SMB1 security issue set the client max to SMB3:

```
server min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
```

Then your usershare add command will not result in an error.

You will of course disable browsing to shares as I explained here: [How to tell Gigolo / GVFS to use SMBv2 for Windows shares?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919967/how-to-tell-gigolo-gvfs-to-use-smbv2-for-windows-shares/926451#926451)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only way I can reproduce that error is by changing the minimum server protocol from LANMAN1 to SMB2 ( or SMB3 ) in smb.conf. Do you have this line in your smb.conf:

```
server min protocol = SMB2
```

Or maybe it somehow got changed in the default. To find out:

```
testparm -sv | grep protocol
```

Comment: Yes, I just found that this might be related. I tried manually accessing the Samba share using "smbclient -L 192.168.2.103 -W WORKGROUP". That finally gave a useful error message: protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE.

Comment: So, yes I had "server min protocol = SMB2" in the smb.conf, I added an entry "protocol = SMB3" not, it still does not work. Maybe I need to restart, instead of restarting the service...

Comment: A restart won't do you any good. I think it's fair to say this is a bug in usershare. The creation of a samba share shouldn't be dependant on the default setting of LANMAN1 as the minimum server dialect.

Comment: I changed my settings to  `server min protocol = NT1` and `server max protocol = SMB2` as mentioned [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0127394) . Now it works. Not sure why it did not work, the page mentiones something about SMB2 not being supported in the kernel.

Comment: That should work although I wouldn't degrade the max protocol. The default is SMB3 which is where Windows and MacOS are these days.